# Jquery flowplayer a href needs two clicks?

Tags: database, jquery-mobile, flowplayer

I have no idea, how to explain this properly, but i try my best.
I have worked with flowplayer in jquery mobile (with multipage).
I have about 20 video sourced from database.

Now the problem:
I don't want all the videos start loading, when i start the video.
I have tried to make javascript to start correct video with '' tag, but it needs two clicks to start video.

Here is link i'm using (sorry, some forms are in finnish) http://www.rakentaja.fi/test/mobv/3mobvid.asp

Don't bother to go in front page, because i haven't finished those sites. 
just pick any of the links and watch what happens.

Please, use google chrome, it's only browser which is the only one what works.

Thank you!

Comment: dont use inline functions `javascript:aloitavid(61,'Valloxsuodpuhdvaihto')`.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a possible way of playing videos dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put links to hardcoded

```
<a href="-previous page-"> Back </a>
```

if it's posible.

That won't be nice, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using inline Javascript functions, do it this way.

```
$('a.ui-link').on('click', function() {
 aloitavid(61,'Valloxsuodpuhdvaihto');
});
```

Since each link has different parameters; you need to add those to the `<a>` link attributes and then pull them to be used in your function.

**Update**

You could do the below. Save video parameters as an attribute `vlink`, then read parameters and pass them to your function `aloitavid()`. [Example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/kL4KA/)

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="ui-link" vlink="60,Valloxyleistailmanvkoneenhuollosta">start video</a>
```

Code

```
$('a.ui-link').on('click', function () {
 var vlink = $(this).attr('vlink').split(",");
 var value1 = vlink[0];
 var value2 = vlink[1];
 aloitavid(value1,value2)
});
```

This results

> value1: 60
>
> value2: Valloxyleistailmanvkoneenhuollosta

Comment: Thank you so much! 
Can i do that like in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/kL4KA/6/)?
Or where should i put that Your code, in separate script or same? and if in separate, how can i link it to flowplayer?  
I'm still learning this thing, sorry about it.

Comment: i tried that what i have put in that example, and it didn't work like i wanted. :(

Comment: @TeemuLaine put the code separately. Add  video data to your links. Anyway, I'll check your code again.

Comment: Thank you, please let me know, if You have any ideas, how to get this working. I appreciate it very much!

Comment: @TeemuLaine try this, and note the changes. I have combined two functions in one, so you dont need `aloitavid` function now. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/kL4KA/

Comment: It still need two clicks?! Thank you!

Comment: @TeemuLaine have you tried exactly what I've done in my latest example?

Comment: I have changed in `<a href vlink="<% = tiedot("id") %>,<% = tiedot("videotiedostonnimi") %>">...</a>` another values. I don't know what can i put in the script code values: 
   `var vlink = $(this).attr('vlink').split(",");
    var value1 = vlink[0];
    var value2 = vlink[1];`

Comment: This example is not working, can You check, if you know why it's not working. http://jsfiddle.net/kL4KA/10/ Thank You!

Comment: @teemulaine it won't work in jsfiddle, try it on your page live. I'll check it anyway.

Comment: I know, it's not working. I don't know how/what to call those  `<% %>`
scripts, can you please comment how can i (if i can) add those scripts in flowplayer function?! I know, it's really unclear, but i have no idea, how to explain it better. Sorry about it!

Comment: Why are using `<% %>`? @teemulaine

Comment: Those brings information and correct names from database, like ID and Videoname. I was told that those works fine in this site. 
`<% = info("id") %>` and in SQL script i set thing, what that info will do... That part works like a charm. Only thing is, that i need to figure out, how/where to put those scripts in flowplayer function. 
Thank You!

Comment: @TeemuLaine when you inject data from SQL into your markup, they should have data instead of code. they cant be added to your script, as scripts accepts such codes.

Comment: Hmm. Okey, i need to figure out something else. Thank you very much, I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: `<% %>` should be within your HTML code, when your code is rendered, they will be translated into values. afterwards, you can use those values into your script. @TeemuLaine